# Event when a document is added to a calendar item

Tags: vba, outlook

I want the event that will fire when a document is added to calendar item.
After that I want to handle that document by moving it to another place (network share).

I open the calendar and drag a Word document from Windows Explorer to a date on the calendar then I need that event to handle.

Code I tried:

```vb
Public WithEvents aaa As Outlook.AppointmentItem
Public WithEvents bbb As Outlook.DocumentItem
Public WithEvents ccc As Outlook.TaskItem
Public WithEvents ddd As Outlook.JournalItem
Public WithEvents eee As Outlook.Items

 

Private Sub aaa_AttachmentAdd(ByVal Attachment As Attachment)

End Sub

Private Sub aaa_BeforeAttachmentAdd(ByVal Attachment As Attachment, Cancel As Boolean)

End Sub

Private Sub bbb_AttachmentAdd(ByVal Attachment As Attachment)

End Sub

Private Sub bbb_BeforeAttachmentAdd(ByVal Attachment As Attachment, Cancel As Boolean)

End Sub


Private Sub ccc_AttachmentAdd(ByVal Attachment As Attachment)

End Sub

Private Sub ccc_BeforeAttachmentAdd(ByVal Attachment As Attachment, Cancel As Boolean)

End Sub


Private Sub ddd_AttachmentAdd(ByVal Attachment As Attachment)

End Sub

Private Sub ddd_BeforeAttachmentAdd(ByVal Attachment As Attachment, Cancel As Boolean)

End Sub

Private Sub eee_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)

End Sub
```

Comment: Would you consider sharing more details on where exactly the problem lies? Do you have any code? Have you tried the MailItem.AttachmentAdd event? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.attachmentadd

Comment: @SnowGroomer Actually I don't have much to show except this, a couple of event handlers with breakpoints and hoping one will work

Answer (score 0):

> I want to find a proper event that will fire when a document is added to calendar item.

It is not clear how a document is added to the Outlook item. Is it attached  as a file? Or a shared link is added to the item?

Anyway, when users attach anything to Outlook items, they must select or open an item and then attach a file there. So, you can handle the [SelectionChange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.explorer.selectionchange) event of the `Explorer` class to be aware which item is currently viewed or selected. And if any file is attached to the selected item you may handle the [AppointmentItem.AttachmentAdd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.appointmentitem.attachmentadd) event which is when an attachment has been added to an instance of the parent object. The `Attachment` that was added to the item is passed as a parameter to the event handler.

You may find the [Implement a wrapper for inspectors and track item-level events in each inspector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/pia/how-to-implement-a-wrapper-for-inspectors-and-track-item-level-events-in-each-inspector) article helpful.

If you want to track calendar item changes like shared links to documents added you need to handle the [Items.ItemChange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.itemchange) event which is fired  when an item in the specified collection is changed.

Comment: I will try this all thanks! BTW I was dragging a file from windows explorer to the outlook calendar itself.

Comment: I guess such files will be added as attachments.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I forgot the basic thing - to set those WithEvents variables in Application_ItemLoad:

```
Private Sub Application_ItemLoad(ByVal Item As Object)
    If (TypeOf Item Is AppointmentItem) Then
        Set aaa = Item
    ElseIf (TypeOf Item Is DocumentItem) Then
        Set bbb = Item
    ElseIf (TypeOf Item Is TaskItem) Then
        Set ccc = Item
    ElseIf (TypeOf Item Is JournalItem) Then
        Set ddd = Item
    ElseIf (TypeOf Item Is Items) Then
        Set eee = Item
    ElseIf (TypeOf Item Is Explorer) Then
        Set fff = Item
    End If
End Sub
```